# Chrome Crashing with whitespaces in Textarea on using onClick="this.select();"

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

i am using Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 (64-bit). Which is Crashing with whitespaces in Textarea on this.select().

```
<style>
.custom-input {
font-size: 12px;
width: 100%;
color: #555555;
}
.parent-div {
white-space: nowrap;
}
.child-div textarea {
white-space: inherit;
}
</style>

<div class="parent-div">
<div class="child-div">


<textarea class="md-input ng-binding" type="text" readonly="" onclick="this.select();"          rows="4">                          &lt;img       src="http://www.nikhilmaheshwari.in"
                      alt="ITs my homepage, see http://www.nikhilmaheshwari.in" height="1" width="1" /&gt;
                    </textarea>

 </div>
</div>
```

Check JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/vqfefjwo/

I know couple of resolutions for it but I am interested in knowing the cause of it. Please suggest if you can share the probable reason.

Edit : its working with "white-space: pre-line;" or "white-space: pre;" or "white-space: pre-wrap;" but not working with "white-space: nowrap;" or "white-space: normal;" or "white-space: inherit;"(if parent is any of normal or nowrap)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner space from `textarea` tag

```
<textarea class="custom-input ng-binding" type="text" readonly="" onclick="this.select()" rows="4">&lt;img src="http://www.nikhilmaheshwari.in" alt="Its my homepage !, see preview @  http://www.nikhilmaheshwari.in" height="1" width="1" /&gt;</textarea>
```

Its working fine for me.

Comment: As mentioned in the query itself, i know the resolution but reason is still unknown. Pls suggest the reason if you are aware.